# making a list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following snippet of code:

```
for i in range(len(unique_example)):
    for j in range(len(unique_example[i])):

        print(name_of_attributes[i])
        print(unique_example[i][j])

        for k in range(len(goal_predicate_list)):
            print(goal_predicate_list[k])

            frequency = len([x for x in examples if x['Predicate'] == goal_predicate_list[k] and
                      x[name_of_attributes[i]] == unique_example[i][j]])

            print(frequency)
```

And the print statements in the given code print the following:

```
Sepal_Length
4.9
Iris-setosa
4
Iris-virginica
1
Iris-versicolor
1

Sepal_Length
6.3
Iris-setosa
0
Iris-virginica
6
Iris-versicolor
3

Sepal_Length
7.6
Iris-setosa
0
Iris-virginica
1
Iris-versicolor
0
```

How can i make a dictionary which would store the data in the dictionary as:

```
 attribute_frequency_dict = {"Sepal_length": 4.9, "Iris-setosa": 4, "Iris-virginica": 1, "Iris-versicolor": 1}
```

and then store all other data in the same way in the following list as:

```
attribute_frequency_list = [ { }, { },...{ } ]
```

Comment: Create an empty `dict` before `for` and add values to it inside the loop.

Comment: Are you sure you want to mix the `"Sepal_Length"` string from `name_of_attributes` and the decimal value from `unique_example` in with the `predicate_list` strings and their frequencies?

Comment: @Blckknght yes, i need the values in the same way, and i am having trouble creating the dictionary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes to the code snippet worked.

```
for i in range(len(unique_example)):
        for j in range(len(unique_example[i])):

            # stores as { "attribute": value, "predicate_value[0]": occurrence, "predicate_value[1]": occurrence}
            attribute_frequency_dict = {name_of_attributes[i]: unique_example[i][j]}

            for k in range(len(goal_predicate_list)):

                frequency = len([x for x in examples if x['Predicate'] == goal_predicate_list[k] and
                                 x[name_of_attributes[i]] == unique_example[i][j]])

                attribute_frequency_dict[goal_predicate_list[k]] = frequency

            attribute_frequency_list.append(attribute_frequency_dict)
```

Created a dictionary and added values to those in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use **range** and **len** to iterate over a sequence.

```
for i, u in enumerate(unique_example):
    for j in range(len(u)):
        # stores as { "attribute": value, "predicate_value[0]": occurrence, "predicate_value[1]": occurrence}
        attribute_frequency_dict = {name_of_attributes[i]: u[j]}
        for p in goal_predicate_list:
            frequency = len([x for x in examples if x['Predicate'] == p and x[name_of_attributes[i]] == u[j]])
            attribute_frequency_dict[p] = frequency
        attribute_frequency_list.append(attribute_frequency_dict)
```